# How to display a textarea as HTML code inside another textarea?

Tags: html, forms, jsp, servlets

I'm developing JSP/Servlet website. I have a form in my JSP page that call Servlet which do some processing then froward the results back to the Same JSP page. 
The form has textarea that get HTML code from the user and I use syntax highlighting tool for the textarea to format the code inside the textarea.

The problem is when I retain the value of textarea after updating the page, if it the entered code contains a textarea element it render the closing tag of nested textarea as the closing tag of the parent textarea. I retain the value in this way:

```
<textarea rows="30" cols="80" id="txtArea" name="txtArea" 
placeholder="Enter your code" >${param.txtArea}</textarea>
```

Here is examples for what is happened:

if user enter this in the textarea everything is retained correctly:

```
    <form >
        <label for="name">Your name:</label><br />
        <input id="name" type="text" />
        <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send email" />
</form>
```

However, if the user enter this:

```
<form >
            <label for="name">Your name:</label><br />
            <input id="name" type="text" />
            <textarea id="message" class="input" name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea>
            <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send email" />
    </form>
```

it will retain just these line :

```
<label for="name">Your name:</label><br />
            <input id="name" type="text" />
            <textarea id="message" class="input" name="message" rows="7" cols="30">
```

Closing textarea tag and everything after that is not retained inside textarea. and render as HTML code. Could anyone help me to find a way to retain all content entered by the user? or how to escape the first closing tag of textarea?

Answer (score 1):

i just surrund my textarea with  tag then use wyswyg plugin from jquery if you need to show the design out put.

```js
<script src="jquery.richtext.js"></script>
```

```html
<textarea value="<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Example page
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea>
        <code>
        some html code here with style<h1>text</h1>
        or any
        </code>
        
        
        </textarea>
    </body>
</html>"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use javascript to assign the desired values to your text area elements. See example below.

Keep in mind that you may need to escaped quotes. You can handle it in java or javascript. Still, javascript is going to be easier to handle what you want comparable to working with java/jsp place holders.

Here is an example to handle it in javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>

<textarea id="outerArea" cols=50 rows=10></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var textAreaValue = '<form>'
        +'  <input type="text"><br>'
        +'  <textarea>Inner Text Area</textarea>'
        +'</form>';
    document.getElementById("outerArea").value = textAreaValue;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT
Answering OP's comment: Javscript still the way to go. Work with JSP and Javascript variables.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function copyContent() {
        document.getElementById("area1").value = ${param.txtArea};
    }
</script>
</header>
<body>
<textarea id="area1" cols=50 rows=10></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I could not use this. I just have 1 textarea in my code in JSP page. The user will enter his html code in that textarea. If the user code does not contain textarea that will be fine and there is no any problems. However, if the user code has a textarea in it here we will have the problem. So, I can't know if the textarea will contain another one or not.

Comment: I want to display for user exactly what he/she enter.

Comment: Still, if you use JSP Place Holders you will run into many other problems. Add the content o the place holder to a javascript variable and assign it to your text area.

Comment: This is not work the textarea is empty after submitting the form. Also, it shows an error in console if I use ${param.txtArea} inside javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the HTML into the textarea tag's value attribute, it's will work correctly.

Like that:

```
<textarea value="<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Example page
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </body>
</html>"></textarea>
```